# Manual focus in Nikon Coolpix P7100

Tags: nikon, manual-focus

Is it possible to focus manually with Nikon Coolpix P7100?

I put my camera on a tripod and tried to make photos of full moon this night, however the camera is unable to find focus on the Moon and all my photos off-focus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://www.nikonusa.com/pdf/manuals/kie88335f7869dfuejdl=-cww2/P7100EN.pdf), page 2 of the reference section (heading: '**Taking Pictures with Manual Focus**') this is possible.

This is the relevant page from the manual:

[image]